# THREE JS RawShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, shader, lighting

I'm trying to build my own shaders using RawShaderMaterial. Right now I've created a basic lighting setup which got me thinking if I was to later on build a scene using the standard THREE.JS lights and I wanted those lights to interact with the custom shaders I built then how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using RawShaderMaterial and not ShaderMaterial? There is a basic demo of [ShaderMaterial with point lights here](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/single_color_point_lights.html)

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take look at [WebGLProgram](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.js)

your raw shader will be taken, parsed and modified
some highlights about how to make use of lights :

make sure you have lights enabled when creating your material

```
material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
     uniforms: uniforms,
     vertexShader: vertex,
     fragmentShader: fragment,
     lights: true
  });
```

you can get the number of lights of each type in scene by including one of special strings inside of your shader code:

```
string.replace( /NUM_DIR_LIGHTS/g, parameters.numDirLights )
        .replace( /NUM_SPOT_LIGHTS/g, parameters.numSpotLights )
        .replace( /NUM_POINT_LIGHTS/g, parameters.numPointLights )
        .replace( /NUM_HEMI_LIGHTS/g, parameters.numHemiLights );
```

take a look at [WebGLLights](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLLights.js) you will be able to acces the lights through uniforms

for example a bit of a fragment shader pseudo code with directional lights (taken from phong material code)

```
#if NUM_DIR_LIGHTS > 0
    struct DirectionalLight {
        vec3 direction;
        vec3 color;
        int shadow;
        float shadowBias;
        float shadowRadius;
        vec2 shadowMapSize;
    };
    uniform DirectionalLight directionalLights[ NUM_DIR_LIGHTS ];
#endif

main(){
```

.
   .

```
GeometricContext geometry;
geometry.position = - vViewPosition;
geometry.normal = normal;
geometry.viewDir = normalize( vViewPosition );
IncidentLight directLight;
#if ( NUM_DIR_LIGHTS > 0 ) && defined( RE_Direct )
   DirectionalLight directionalLight;
   for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_DIR_LIGHTS; i ++ ) {
       directionalLight = directionalLights[ i ];
       directLight = getDirectionalDirectLightIrradiance( directionalLight, geometry );        
       RE_Direct( directLight, geometry, material, reflectedLight );
   }
#endif
```

it is not complete but it should illustrate the main points, you can always create a material for example MeshPhong, add it to scene and look at the vertex and fragment code it compiled from(or catch it inside WebGLProgram as it is beign parsed for a more readable version as it unrolls loops and replaces the light nums...)